# If both subjects are the same, can I still use a singular verb?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

Is this sentence correct?

> My mother and best friend loves cooking as much as I do.

Considering that I'm referring to the same person here, would it be better if I put it this way:

> My mother and my best friend loves cooking as much as I do.

Comment: Nicole's answer is correct, but I would avoid this phrasing.  Even without the 'my' it still sounds like you're referring to two different people and just got the subject-verb agreement wrong.  I would suggest an alternate phrasing that clarifies that 'best friend' is a qualifier on mother and not a separate person.  For instance:  "My mother, my best friend, loves cooking as much as I do."  Then there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the same person, then "My mother and best friend loves cooking as much as I do" is correct. If you say "My mother and *my* best friend", it sounds like you're talking about two different people.

**Edit:** (Thanks to @sumelic - I was searching for a while until I saw the added tags that helped me figure out exactly what parts of speech these were.)

I found [this article](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/compound-subjects-and-verb-number) from Merriam Webster. In it, it states:

> SINGULAR SUBJECT: The dog barks every morning.
>   ...
>   TWO SINGULAR: The dog and the cat bother me.
>   TWO PLURAL: The dogs and the cats bother me.
>   ONE SINGULAR, ONE PLURAL: The dog and cats bother me.

Since your mother is **one** singular subject, it should mirror the first sentence:

> The dog barks every morning. = My mother and best friend loves cooking as much as I do.

Comment: Are there any explanation to this or reference that I can check? I'll have to teach this to my students.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my answer to include that.

Answer (score 1):

The only way the singular would work is the apposition:

***My mother, my best friend***, loves cooking as much as I do.

or the better-sounding non-restrictive relative:

***My mother, who is also my best friend***, loves cooking as much as I do.

Comment: I disagree. The structure works just fine for me. "The king and ruler of England **is**..." In speech, intonation would clearly indicate that the mother and best friend were the same person.